# SQL replacing a field with specific text

Tags: sql

I have the following fields for my sql view:

`name | description | date`

where I have to query for the `max` and `min` dates and print the new view as

`status      |       name       |              description              |  starting`

where in the `status` field is a text field will show `longest time` and `shortest time`. This field is completely new, and isn't built into any of the tables, how would I go in creating this field in the view?

EDIT:

I want to add the extra field `status` to my view, so make an extra column. As such, I have

```
create or replace view one (name, description, starting) as
-- SQL STUFF HERE...
```

from this view, I need to grab the max and min from it and union those two selections together, but add an extra column which describes whether that row has the `longest time` or the `shortest time`. To get

`create or replace view two (status, name, description, starting) as`

at the moment I've written up

```
select name, longname, max(starting) from one
union
select name, longname, min(starting) from one;
```

and this prints out the three columns, but I need to add the extra fourth column `status` but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Can you post the SQL you have so far?

Comment: i just want to know how to create the status column

Comment: what is the logic behind status column? how will it get produced? Post your query or expected results with data along with explanation

Comment: @bjan i've added some extra information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a simple string:

```
select 'longest time' AS status, name, longname, max(starting) from one
union
select 'shortest time' AS status, name, longname, min(starting) from one;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are wanting Starting to show as you don't describe it but group by is what you are looking for and you can run aggregating functions over your date to get the information you desire. You may want a different date format so you might want to use Convert rather than cast to get the dates out in the format you want.

```
SELECT
    CAST(MAX(Date) AS NVARCHAR(20)) + ' ,' 
    + CAST(MIN(Date) AS NVARCHAR(20)) AS Status
    Name
    Description

FROM tblMyTables
GROUP BY 
    Name, 
    Description
```